How to diagnose issues with iPhones loosing network connectivity?
So I currently have the iPhone 15 Pro, but once every few days and sometimes even every day my iPhone stops working; videos won't load, sounds won't play and messages will not send. I have done just about everything I could think of and the only conclusion I can make is that my device is not the problem.
The reason for that is that this not only happened with my 15 Pro, but also with my iPhone 13, two (different) iPhone XR, and even a temporary iPhone SE. Is this connected to my Apple ID? I have no issues with anything else but my iPhone.
If this is familiar to anyone a solution or advice would be gratefully appreciated.
thanks.

Welcome to AskDifferent! Questions usually are better received when they (including the summary) focus on the problem to be solved and not so much on a presumed cause. Can you please edit your post accordingly?

Having said that: Are all devices in the same network when the problem occurs? Do you have any VPN enabled? Do you use iCloud Private Relay?
